ビデオデータでフレームごとにバウンディングボックスを作成し、そこバウンディングボックス内の物体を分類することは可能ですか？
研究でビデオデータを用いて、物体の検出および分類を一貫して行いたいと考えています。ビデオに写っている物体を検出しそれを各フレームごとにバウンディングボックスを使用して、それをCNNやLSTMを組み合わせて、分類することは可能ですか？

Yoloなどを利用することで可能かと思います。ご自身で実装したい場合も参考になるかと思います。
